# Login with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to create a Login with AJAX and PHP to display error messages more smoother.

My HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="loginMail" name="loginMail" class="text"> 
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" name="pass" class="text"><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="autologin" value="1">  Remember me:  | <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitLogin" id="submitLogin" class="submit" value="Sign In"><br />
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
$('#submitLogin').click(function()
{
    var email = $('#loginMail').val();
    var pass = $('#pass').val();
    $.post('login.php', 
        {email: email, pass: pass}, 
        function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        });
});
```

My PHP

```
<?php
include('database.php');
$pdo = new database();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
#$email = 'web.de';
#$pass = 'pw';

$qry = $pdo->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userbasics WHERE email = :email AND pass =     :pass");
$qry->bindParam(':email', $email);
$qry->bindParam(':pass', $pass);
$qry->execute();
#$result = $qry->fetchAll();
$count = $qry->rowCount();

if($count == 1){
    echo "Eingeloggt!"; 
    header("Location: http://www.google.de");
}
else{
    echo "E-Mailadresse oder Passwort falsch!"; 
}

/*foreach($result as $row){
    echo $row['email']; 
}*/

?>
```

When I'm just calling the PHP-Script with defined data it returns me what it should do. So I guess it's a problem in the Javascript-Part. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you used your browser dev. tools to observe the POST request and response?

Comment: Turn on your web developer console in your web browser to highlight any Javascript issues.

Comment: You can't modify header information after you echo'ed something.

Comment: Does the alert pop up?

Comment: @juco - Yes, the error console says nothing. The Post request and response are empty. :s

Comment: @11684 - I already deleted it (the header information) - Error stays the same and no alert to be followed

Answer (score 0):

Change following code in php

```
if($count == 1){
echo "Eingeloggt!"; 
header("Location: http://www.google.de");
 }
else{
  echo "E-Mailadresse oder Passwort falsch!"; 
}
```

To

```
if($count == 1){
echo "Eingeloggt!"; 
} else{
  echo "E-Mailadresse oder Passwort falsch!"; 
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code -

```
if($count == 1){
    echo "Eingeloggt!"; 
    header("Location: http://www.google.de");
}
```

is wrong... You can't set headers after `echo`ing something. Why do you want to `echo` that thing when you are redirecting the user to a page? Well if you're thinking that if redirection fails, then the page shouldn't be blank and it should display some message, then try this -

```
if($count == 1){
    header("Location: http://www.google.de");
    exit("Eingeloggt!");
}
```

Well for the jQuery part, I don't see anything wrong.

Also, since you are not `submit`ing form anywhere you are just `post`ing it through ajax, set `form` as

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="return false;">
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I changed it and now it doesn't reload the page, but still doesn't echo anything.

Comment: I believe `onsubmit="return false;"` is the preferred method, instead of `action="..."`.